# createBottomTabNavigator can't change tab from route 3 to route 2

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I use createBottomTabNavigator in react navigation v3 and I have 3 route like that:

```
const Route = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeRoute
    }
    Post: {
      screen: PostRoute
    },
    Mark: {
      screen: MarkRoute
    },
  }
)
```

but the problem or better say bug comes when I want to navigate from tab Mark to Post that doesn't navigate and change tab :(

any body can solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: You should show us the code where you are navigating between the tabs. From here, we can only tell you what you are generally supposed to do to navigate. We can't help you with what you have done wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For navigation, you use the **navigate()** function of the prop of the button you are using. For example,
If we define our **createBottomTabNavigator** to be,

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  }
);
```

We would move to the **Settings** tab using the navigate function of the button as seen below,

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Settings"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are more detailed examples, [TAB-BASED-NAVIGATION](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Define your route like this

```
const Route = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomeRoute,
            Post: PostRoute,
            Mark: MarkRoute,
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                return <View/>
            },
        }),
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'red',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray'
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'black'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 12
            },
        },
    }
);
```

Comment: I have edited my answer and added options for title and also for tab icon, label is auto displayed by react-navigation.
Hope this helps